# Python2.7 - How to access the first occurence of a value in a dictionary and change it?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, key-value

I have just started learning about Python (2.7) and computer programming in general using online resources and free online university courses. (I am only a few weeks in)

I have been working on a project to apply every new thing I learn.

I had a list which I wanted to keep at a specific length (for instance 6):

```
list = ["item", "second_item", "third_item", "empty", "empty", "empty"]
```

Then I learned how to use dictionaries and wanted to change this list into a dictionary:

```
list = {1:"item", 2:"second_item", 3:"third_item", 4:"empty", 5:"empty", 6:"empty"}
```

I wanted to add things to 'list' by referencing the first occurrence of "empty", when it was still a list, I used:

```
if "empty" in list:                                   
    addeditem=inventory.index("empty")
    list[addeditem]="newitem"
    print "Added newitem to list!"
else:
    print "list is full!"
```

If I try to do this with a dictionary, it doesn't work. I believe it is because when I use`if "empty" in list:` it thinks I'm trying to reference a key, when I would like to reference the first occurrence of "empty" as a value and then change that value to "newitem".

I have a workaround that goes like this:

```
    if list[1]=="empty":                 
        list[1]="newitem"
        print "Added newitem to list!"
    elif list[2]=="empty":
        list[2]="newitem"
        print "Added newitem to list!"
    elif list[3]=="empty":
        list[3]="newitem"
        print "Added newitem to list!"
    elif list[4]=="empty":
        list[4]="newitem"
        print "Added newitem to list!"
    elif list[5]=="empty":
        list[5]="newitem"
        print "Added newitem to list!"
    elif list[6]=="empty":
        list[6]="newitem"
        print "Added newitem to list!"
    else:
        print "list is full!"
```

This method seems like a lot of work for something that was much easier to do with a list. I'm wondering if there is a better way to add things to a dictionary, not at specific keys, but at the first occurrence of a specific value. I would like to keep the keys the same.
I hope I have been specific enough in asking my question.

If you need me to explain more, please let me know. I'm still studying dictionaries but so far I haven't found a better way to do this. Again, I am only in my first month of learning programming of any kind so I really appreciate the patience in answering this kind of question!

Comment: What made you decide to convert this to a dict, when it looks like the list was working just fine?

Comment: It was more that I'm always trying to apply what new things I learn to the project I've been working on. Also I thought it would be easier for me to reference items in a dictionary if they had keys, instead of items in a list by memorizing which slot [0,1,2,3] they inhabit.

Comment: If you're using 1, 2, 3, etc as the keys of the dictionary though, it doesn't make a difference, seeing as you still have to know which key in [1, 6]

Comment: This is true. Today I learned something new though, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this approach is there's no concept of order in dictionaries. Dictionaries are hashes, the order in which you insert the different keys may have nothing to do with the order in which those keys are ultimately hashed. For the purposes of the code you have already written, you could optimize it by using a loop instead with a boolean marking whether or not the list could be added to, which I have written below as an example. However, if you need to maintain some kind of order, then a dictionary probably isn't the right data structure to be using either way.

```
added = False
for i in range(1,7):
    if list[i] == "empty":
        list[i] = "newitem"
        print "Added newitem to list!"
        added = True
        break
if not added:
    print "list is full!"
```

Comment: This seems like it would work a lot better, and is a lot less text than my workaround. Thank you, I'll try it!